# Erro ao tentar conectar ao SQL Server com CodeIgniter e PHP 7

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, xampp, php-7

Boa tarde, comecei a ter problemas com meu CI ao atualizar meu ambiente de desenvolvimento (windows + xammp) e produção (ubuntu + apache) para a mais recente versão do PHP 7.1.10.

Ao tentar conectar ao Microsoft SQL Server recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Call to
>   undefined function mssql_connect() Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\psa\system\database\drivers\mssql\mssql_driver.php
>   Line Number: 113 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\psa\index.php Line:
>   315 Function: require_once

Já baixei os drives mais recentes no site da Microsoft, e segui alguns exemplos, mas continuo com o mesmo problema.

Meu php.info me retorna que o suporte a SQL Server está habilitado.

> Registered PHP Streams php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip,
>   compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, sqlsrv, phar
>
> PDO support enabled
>
> PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlsrv
>
> pdo_sqlsrv support enabled
>
> ExtensionVer 4.3.0+9904

Se alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema e já conseguiu solucionar, e quiser nos contar sua experiencia, desde já agradeço.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

Sinto lhe informar, mas a função `mssql_connect()` foi removida a partir do `PHP 7.0.0` como é possível verificar no manual [aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php).

Agora você deve usar funções alternativas como [sqlsrv_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) ou [odbc_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)
.

Comment: Boa tarde, desde já agradeço.

Você teria um exemplo de como configurar o CodeIgniter com essas configurações?

Answer (score 0):

Alguém teria um exemplo de configuração do CodeIgniter para conectar ao SQL Server usando o PHP7?

Usando o drive odbc ou sqlsrv já que o mssql foi descontinuado.

Esse exemplo não funcionou.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '192.168.0.5',
    'username' => 'usuario',
    'password' => 'senha',
    'database' => 'nome_banco',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Desde já agradeço.